# Pare Cloud Code getHours() changes all variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, time

I'm writing a node.js function using Parse Open Source's cloud code. Yet for some reason changing the hours on one variable changes other ones?!

```
var beforeTime = item.get("date")
var afterTime = item.get("date")
console.log("before " + beforeTime.getHours())
console.log("after " + afterTime.getHours())
original.log("original " + item.get("date").getHours())

/*
All off these print out the same (i.e. 15)
*/

beforeTime.setHours(beforeTime.getHours() - request.params.hours)

console.log("before " + beforeTime.getHours())
console.log("after " + afterTime.getHours())
original.log("original " + item.get("date").getHours())

/*
All off these ALSO print out the same (i.e. 14) !!!???
*/
```

Comment: I imagine that this is a shallow/deep copy issue. There are loads of threads on this site showing different ways of deep copying in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

beforeTime and afterTime are both getting set to instances of the same object.

Try `var afterTime = new Date(item.get("date").toString());`

Comment: This will create a totally new separate date object from the old date's value.